# Probability of a Full house given at least 2 aces

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I need to find the probability of $$P(full \space house \mid at \space least \space two \space  aces)$$ and $$P(at \space least \space two \space  aces \mid full \space house)$$

I have found the $$P(full \space house) =\dfrac{13\cdot 12\cdot \binom{4}{3}\cdot\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{52}{5}} \space and \space p(2 \space aces) = \dfrac {13\cdot \binom{4}{3}\cdot \binom{12}{3}\cdot 4\cdot 4\cdot 4}{\binom{52}{5}}$$

Let A = Full house and B = 2 aces

If im on the right track $$P(A\mid B) = \dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
But im lost of what the intersction of the two of them would be.

Answer (score 1):

"Full house with at least 2 aces" can be broken down into two cases which can be counted separately:

- full house with 3 aces and 2 non-aces
- full house with 3 non-aces and 2 aces

After adding the two counts, divide by $\binom{52}{5}$.